# how to show div alternately

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php 
  $result1 = db_getarticles( array('campaigns_id' => $SYS_campaign) );
  if (!is_null($result1)) { 
    while ( $row = $result1->fetch_object() ) {
?>

<div class="section">
<div class="leftinfo" style="height:178px;width:408;" >
<?php
      echo "<img style='height:178px;width:402px;' src='$SYS_folder/images/articles/$row->imagearticle' alt=''   />"; 
?>
  </div>
  <div class="rightinfo">
  <strong> 
<?php 
      echo $row->titlearticle; 
?>
</strong></br>
<?php 
      echo $row->descparticle; 
?>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
<div class="seperator"></div>
</div>
<?php 
    }
  } 
?>
```

Hello, I want to show alternatively image and decription 1 record on left side image and other on right side image. Can any help me out? Thanks.

Comment: please make your code more readable by re-indenting it again

Comment: i have done with code formatting

Comment: this image and description iscoming dynamically now its showing one after other but iwant to show it alternatively like...1st record image on left and description on right and for 2nd record vicecersa

Comment: Have you tried anything with CSS? We like to see some effort at solving your own problem. Try googleing CSS `floats` or `inline-block`  I would also recomend reviewing your HTML output and use the appropriate `hx` tag for your title and remove the br tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you are asking how to determine the alternate divs for applying different styles.

You should use CSS classes to give the divs alternate effect.

```
.section{width:500px; height:200px;}
.rightinfo{ float : right; }
.leftinfo{ float : left; }
.section img{width:402px; height:178px;}
```

In your PHP code before while loop have a variable

```
$style = 0;
```

and in while loop increment and check the value (odd / even) for applying correct classes.

```
$style++;
if($style % 2 == 0){
    $imgClass = 'leftinfo';
    $descClass = 'rightinfo';
} else {
    $imgClass = 'rightinfo';
    $descClass = 'leftinfo';
}
```

assign these classes to your HTML elements.

```
<div class="<?php echo $imgClass; ?>"> .... </div>
<div class="<?php echo $descClass; ?>"> .... </div>
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tmc8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Having seen what you are after try the following:

- Add a class variable for the section class
- Use there ternary operator to set it.
- Use CSS to change positioning.

This will make CSS more responsible for position an may result in less refactoring php code if you need to change the layout.

```
<?php 
  $sectionClass = "" #new class for section
  $result1 = db_getarticles( array('campaigns_id' => $SYS_campaign) );
  if (!is_null($result1)) { 
    while ( $row = $result1->fetch_object() ) {
       #set section class as needed
       $sectionClass = ($sectionClass == "section" ? "section alt" : "section"); 
?>

<div class="<?php echo $sectionClass ?>">    
<?php
      echo "<img  src='$SYS_folder/images/articles/$row->imagearticle' alt=''   />"; 
?>

  <div class="info">
  <h2> 
<?php 
      echo $row->titlearticle; 
?>
</h2>
<?php 
      echo $row->descparticle; 
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
    }
  } 
?>
```

Now use the following CSS:

```
.section{width:500px; height:200px; clear:both;}

.section img{width:402px; height:178px;float:left}
.section .info {float:right}

/*Swap Position Of image and description*/
.section.alt img{float:right}
.section.alt .info {float:left; }
```

Example from HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/FttQ5/3/

**End Update**

If future please show more effort at solving your problems.

I've used `display:inline-block` to give you your 2-columns. Please see the article on the pros and cons of using `inline-block` over `floats`

Change your php to generate the following HTML

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="leftinfo">
        <img style='height:178px;width:402px;' src='' alt='' />
    </div>
    <div class="rightinfo"> <strong>Title 1</strong>
        <br />Dscription 1</div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="leftinfo" >
        <img style='height:178px;width:402px;' src='' alt='' />
    </div>
    <div class="rightinfo"> <strong>Title 2</strong>
        <br />Dscription 2</div>
</div>
```

Now add the following CSS

```
.section {
position:relative;
margin-bottom:5px;
}

.section .leftinfo, .section .rightinfo {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.leftinfo{ height:178px;width:408;}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FttQ5/1/

Please note that you would be better of putting your title in an aprropriate `hx` tag eg `h1`....`h6` and the image could be styled with CSS classes. E.g:

```
.section img {height:178px;width:402px; }
```

Further more there is no reason for the image to be wrapped in a `div` at all

Slightly optimized example: http://jsfiddle.net/FttQ5/2/